# combine data from different tables into one table between date ranges SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Below is my data from different tables.

```
ID      StudentID  Tablename    StartDate   enddate
8849    2          Service      11/4/2010   11/2/2011
8850    2          Service      11/4/2010   11/2/2011
16512   2          Placement    11/4/2010   6/30/2011
16513   2          Placement    09/01/2011  11/02/2011
```

I want output like below:

```
SE_ID  ST_ID  PL_ID   StartDate    enddate
8849   2      16512   11/04/2010   06/30/2011
8849   2      16513   09/01/2011   11/02/2011
8850   2      16512   11/04/2010   06/30/2011
8850   2      16513   09/01/2011   11/02/2011
```

I have tried below SQL. I am getting correct result but Query is taking long. Is there any other way I can achieve same result not using left outer join?

```
with 
Daterange as 
( 
select SE_ID,se_st_id as ST_ID,'Service' AS Tablename, SE_StartDate AS StartDate ,se_enddate as enddate from spipublic.service 
union 
select PL_ID,pl_st_id as ST_ID,'Placement' AS Tablename, PL_StartDate AS StartDate,pl_enddate as enddate from spipublic.placement
union 
select SU_ID,su_st_id as ST_ID,'StudentStatus' AS Tablename,SU_StartDate AS StartDate,SU_EndDate as enddate from spipublic.studentstatus
)
select   Distinct    
      D.ST_ID
      ,SU.SU_ID
      , PL.PL_ID
     , SE.SE_ID
     ,D.startdate
    ,D.EndDate
from spipublic.studentstatus SU
inner join Daterange D 
on SU.SU_ST_ID=D.ST_ID and (SU.SU_EndDate IS NULL OR SU.SU_ENDDate>D.Startdate) and SU.SU_STartDate<D.EndDate 
left join spipublic.service SE 
on SE.SE_ST_ID=D.ST_ID and (SE.SE_ENDDate IS NULL OR SE.SE_ENDDATE>D.StartDate) and SE.SE_StartDate<D.EndDate 
left join spipublic.placement PL 
on PL.PL_ST_ID=D.ST_ID and (PL.PL_EndDate IS NULL OR PL.PL_EndDate>D.StartDate) and PL.PL_StartDate<D.EndDate 
where D.st_id=2
```

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between your table of data 1 and table of data 2. Can you describe in words what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: There just isn't enough information here for anybody to offer any real help. We have no idea what your tables, index, data is like. We can't help with performance without those kinds of details. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Table 2 is the output I am trying to achieve. Basically, I want to combine student's all data like enrollment, placement, service within same date range in one table

Comment: Add `where st_id=2` to each of the select statements in the union. Right now you're pumping a lot of data into memory and the selecting a very small set.

Comment: I need to run the query for all students. I did st_id=2 to get above result for one student only.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say from the example given, but off the top of my head UNION ALL might speed it up.

Comment: The first chart is the result of union all from placement, service and enrollment table. How do I aggregate data after that result set?